# Is that possible to ignore the inherited font-size?

Tags: css, svg

I have an `OpenLayers` map (`SVG` renderer), that contains dozens of bubbles/features and as I'm clustering them, I also apply a custom `fontSize` style to them -- via `OpenLayers.Style`.

On the other hand I have a reset rule like `* { font-size: 14px; }`. The `circle`,`text` and `tspan` elements -- the bubbles on the map, they all inherit the font size property from `*` and then that out-weight the inline attribute of `font-size` that OpenLayers apply on the `text` element.

If I temporary remove that inherited `font-size` from any of above elements via Chrome Developer Tools for example, then everything gets fine.

Any ideas how should I overcome this problem? Note that:

- The font sizes are dynamic. I calculate them when OpenLayers clusters the features. So I can't apply a static `class` or `style` to them.
- I don't want to use `:not` selector
- If I remove the `font-size` from `*`, then how do you suggest to apply it to the all the other elements?
- Is there anything like `!not-important` or `do-not-inherit` in CSS?

The actual `text` node looks like this -- barebones:

```
<text font-size="19.2px">
    <tspan>19</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Why can't you simply declaratively apply the desired styles to the elements in questions? That would override the styles applied with the * selector.

Comment: @ChrisHardie they are dynamic, I can't apply a `class` or `style` to them. I calculate them via JS in OpenLayers when clustering happens.

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with OpenLayers. What about wrapping those dynamic element in a containing element, and then applying a font size to that container?

Comment: If you are resetting the font size using `*`, you're effectively preventing inheritance.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Well, OpenLayers generates all of those things, so I can't simply jump in and do my stuff. :\

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn But that also overwrites OpenLayer's inline font-size attribute as well, is that really supposed to do so?

Comment: What if you try ` body{ font-size:14px;} ` or at least a parent at a high level instead of `*`

Comment: @xpy You're the man! That just worked! Please send your comment as an answer, so I can accept it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try `body{ font-size:14px;}` or at least a parent at a high level instead of `*`?